# How many or which resources will a scavenger take when I make a 'Call for Scavengers' radio assistance call?

Tags: state-of-decay

If I make a 'Call for Scavengers' [radio assistance call](http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/Radio) in a location that has more than one [resource](http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/Resources) crates of different types and a bunch of other items still in there...

- How many or which items will a scavenger collect?
- Is this affected by a scavenger's [backpack](http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/Backpacks) size or carrying weight capacity?
- Will he/she collect all crates and resources? Or only a specific number of crates and/or resources?
- What determines which type of items or resource crates a scavenger will carry in his/her rucksack?
- Can scavenger 'empty' (the resources and loot of) a previously non-empty location?

I'm playing the Steam Early Access version on the PC.

Answer (score 3):

- Scavengers won't collect items.
- Just like the survivor you control, each scavenger can only carry ONE type of resource by packing it in a Rucksack, which is not affected by inventory space or carrying capacity.
- If you "Call Scavenger" by selecting a resource from the loot screen, he/she will collect that type of resource. If you "Call Scavenger" from the radio menu when there are more than 1 type of resource in the location, my guess is that they loot up the first thing they find.

Comment: Do you know what determines which type of resource crates a scavenger will carry in his/her rucksack, if a location has two or more different types of resource crates in it?

Comment: I notice that if I choose "Call Scavenger" from the loot screen, he/she will always loot the type of material I selected before radioing home. If I choose "Call Scavenger" from the radio menu, I believe he/she will start searching the area from the first floor and pack up the first resource that is found (since it apparently is easiest to do, both in real life and when coding :D).